# IE7 & IE 8 Blocking images and css loading

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, widget, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on JavaScript widget to embed some reviews of my site to show on any site who copied my code. I followed this blog (http://blog.swirrl.com/articles/creating-asynchronous-embeddable-javascript-widgets/#final-embed-solution) and when i integrate their widget everything working fine. But when i do it same with my widget IE7 is hanging.

Here is the my testing link http://tech4sys.com/testing/jswidget/

It's working on all other browsers except IE, Please test above link in IE<9 only.

PS. I've removed image src to test but still it is blocking loading dashboard_widget.php and never loads.

Thanks

Comment: Who cares about IE7 ?

Comment: @adeneo How about IE8, is IE7 dead you mean?

Comment: @adeneo Windows Vista included IE7 so it's not end-of-life for it tomorrow (which is when XP reaches end of life) :( .. but that said, the usage is tiny.

Comment: @adeneo on which version you check above link, Is that working for you except images? Try refresh twice and let me know please..

Comment: @PraveenReddy - I don't even have IE8, I do however have IE11 which has an emulator, but I'm too lazy to fire it up.